# This model is not supported: Input tensor 0 does not have a name

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow-lite

On Android Studio, I'm not able to view the model metadata, even though I had added the metadata in Python manually. I get the error:

> This model is not supported: input tensor 0 does not have a name.

[image]

### My attempts at fixing:

I added the layer name to the tensorflow input layer, using:

```py
img_input = Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=1, name="input_image")
```

I even checked it in Netron, and the input layer showed up as `input_image` as expected: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by copying 1 line from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#adding_metadata), I needed to add a specific property to the `TensorMetadataT` object, `input_meta.name = "image"`. This does not come from the model layer name, but needs to be **manually** added.

```py
input_meta.name = "image_input"
```

*Weirdly:* This wasn't a problem before, but for some reason, my previous code broke and I needed this change.